# Can highcharts generate a 3d column chart like this?

Tags: highcharts

Can someone provide a demo?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the z axis,

```
 zAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 3,
      categories: [1,2,3,4],
      labels: {
        y: 5,
        rotation: 18
      }
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/qz47f7ve/)**

[`Source : Generate a 3d column chart`](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/can-highcharts-generate-a-3d-chart-like-this-t37544/)

Comment: Hi, why do you use my example from highcharts forum? If you want to use it just paste link to source.

Comment: @stpoa sure i will add it, i forgot the link. Please add here

Comment: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/can-highcharts-generate-a-3d-chart-like-this-t37544/

Thank you.

Comment: how do you turn off the bottom series toggles? the dots that say series 1, 2, 3, 4?